# Storing Dictionary with multiple keys with multiple values into class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary that has multiple keys with multiple values and I want to store them into an object list rather than the dictionary.  My results look like this:

```
PLAB {'price': '9.450000', 'quantity': '8.0000', 'average_buy_price': '9.3000', 'equity': '75.60', 'percent_change': '1.61', 'equity_change': '1.200000', 'type': 'stock', 'name': 'Photronics', 'id': '2ae1c2e1-5c68-4d73-ba82-9d14fcf57fa6', 'pe_ratio': '16.187542', 'percentage': '5.63'}
CAIMMR {'price': '8.430000', 'quantity': '12.0000', 'average_buy_price': '8.4200', 'equity': '101.16', 'percent_change': '0.12', 'equity_change': '0.120000', 'type': 'stock', 'name': 'Immersion', 'id': 'bcf02154-1068-4f96-999a-f7ecd7724112', 'pe_ratio': '4.734742', 'percentage': '7.53'}
SH {'price': '19.680000', 'quantity': '4.0000', 'average_buy_price': '19.4400', 'equity': '78.72', 'percent_change': '1.23', 'equity_change': '0.960000', 'type': 'stock', 'name': 'Meta Financial', 'id': '7eb2c5f5-2c3c-46ec-b1d7-89c84c00b133', 'pe_ratio': '10.124530', 'percentage': '5.86'}
```

I would like for these values to be store in an object that I have set up below:

```
class StockProperties(object):
    def __init__(self, ticker, price, quantity, average_buy_price, equity, percent_change, equity_change, option_type, name, option_id, pe_ratio, portfolio_percentage):
        self.ticker = ticker
        self.price = price
        self.quantity = quantity
        self.average_buy_price = average_buy_price
        self.equity = equity
        self.percent_change = percent_change
        self.equity_change = equity_change
        self.type = option_type
        self.name = name
        self.option_id = option_id
        self.pe_ratio = pe_ratio
        self.portfolio_percentage = portfolio_percentage
```

How can I iterate through the keys and values of the dict so that I can store it in this class?

Comment: This looks like a good use of ** unpacking. You could do plab_object = StockProperties(**PLAB) if they matched exactly, but they do not. Some of the args have slightly different names, and ticker is missing entirely. It would be better if the constructor took (self, **kwargs) and had defaults for missing arguments, or raised its own error if a default is unacceptable.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
class StockProperties(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)
```

Other option, maybe, would be to use [DotMap](https://github.com/drgrib/dotmap)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Python 3.7+, use `dataclass` which accepts dict to initialize the object.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
@dataclass
class StockProperties:
        ticker :str
        price :str
        quantity :str
        average_buy_price :str
        equity :str
        percent_change :str
        equity_change :str
        type :str
        name :str
        option_id :str
        pe_ratio :str
        portfolio_percentage :str

props = {'price': '9.450000', 'quantity': '8.0000', 'average_buy_price': '9.3000', 'equity': '75.60', 'percent_change': '1.61', 'equity_change': '1.200000', 'type': 'stock', 'name': 'Photronics', 'id': '2ae1c2e1-5c68-4d73-ba82-9d14fcf57fa6', 'pe_ratio': '16.187542', 'percentage': '5.63'}
stock = StockProperties(**props)
```

But the only condition is **dict** should contain **all** the field names. You can also use **default** values in dataclass to avoid missing keys in dict problem.